# How do I use $_GET["id"] securely with PDO query?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to get the id of a page from the url and use it to retrieve the information from the database. I want to ensure that the id is an integer with a length less than 4 and redirect to a parent page if not.

```
if(isset($_GET["id"])) {
    $id = (int) $_GET["id"];
    // If id is longer than 4 redirect
    if(strlen($id) > 4) {
        header("Location: /parent.php");
        exit;
    }
    try {
        $sth = $dbh -> prepare("SELECT id, title, etc, FROM table WHERE id = :id");
        $sth -> bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $sth -> execute();
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        // print $e -> getMessage();
        echo "Error";
        exit;
    }
    $feature = $sth -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    // If query result is empty redirect
    if($feature == false) {
        header("Location: /parent.php");
        exit;
    }
    $sth = null;
} else { // If id isn't set redirect
    header("Location: /parent.php");
    exit;
}
```

Is the way I'm doing this secure/correct? I'm still getting to grips with this sort of thing so am second guessing myself.

Also, it seems to work as I intended except when the id is set to something like 123abc (child.php?id=123abc) which it interprets as 123 and still loads the information for id 123. Because I'm casting the type is it just ignoring the abc part? Should I be concerned that it still loads and doesn't redirect to parent?

Comment: Why are you checking string length on something that you've just cast into an integer? :)

Comment: If you want to test the ID before converting to an integer, use `strlen($_GET['id'])`.

Comment: The PDO part of your code is fine for securing the query.

Comment: Question is why should an id of more than 4 characters be a problem in the first place?

Comment: @Jack I think my thought process was that it might stop longer injection strings being attempted but I suppose casting it as an int will stop that anyway. Do you think there is any point in having it?

Comment: Have a look into the difference of `(int)$val` cast and `intval($val);`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [input filtering](http://php.net/filter) instead to make sure the passed identifier is indeed an integer; whether it's bigger than 9999 shouldn't matter, but perhaps testing for a positive integer is a good idea:

```
if (($id = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'id', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT)) !== false && $id > 0) {
    // id was passed and it's a valid integer
} else {
    // evil request, die die
}
```

The use of prepared statements already mitigates a potential SQL injection attack, so the rest of your code doesn't have to change, though I would personally try to make a single failure flow instead of four separate (but nearly identical) ones.

Comment: Thank you. I agree the separate redirects seemed awkward but I wasn't sure how else I could do it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, by casting the input to integer, you have circumvented any sql injection attacks.
And by using bind variables you have prevented sql injection attacks again. :)

And that you use strlen on an int is a little ugly, so I would advise to check $id > 9999. Though you will probably not notice the difference.